# Attach Access Token in API call Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

Im sending id ,accessToken as a parameter to my API, they are redux store states, I want to attach my accessToken in my header.Authorization and send it together with the id of the book. Here's what I've tried

```
book.js

const { user, isError, message } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

console.log(user.accessToken) /// im getting a token here
dispatch(likeBook(book._id, user.accessToken))
```

```
bookSlice.js


export const likeBook = createAsyncThunk('/likebook', async(id, accessToken, thunkAPI) => {

    
    const API = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000' });

    API.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
  
    req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
 

    return req;
    });

  
    try {
       
      return await API.patch(`/books/${id}/likeBook`);
              
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString()
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
  }

    
})
```

but in my server when I try reading the header and access token that I sent im getting [object,object] and cant verify the token and getting and error 403

```
const likeBook = async (req, res) => {

    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization || req.headers.Authorization;
    if (!authHeader?.startsWith('Bearer ')) return res.sendStatus(401);
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];


    console.log(authHeader,token)
    


    jwt.verify(
        token,
        process.env.SECRET,
        (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) return res.sendStatus(403); //invalid token
            _id = decoded.UserInfo._id;
        }
    );
}
```

Is what im doing here correct? or is there any work around for this, I tried importing my store.js in this file to get the states instead but im getting error Cannot access '**WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT**' before initialization when importing store

Comment: How are you calling your async thunk? What value are you passing for `accessToken`?

Comment: @Phil in my frontend im getting my accessToken from user state and then the values are passed to the api as parameters together with the id

Comment: I cannot guess what your code looks like. Please [edit] your question

Comment: @Phil done editing it with my frontend code, hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

The payload creator you're passing to `createAsyncThunk` has the wrong signature:

```
async(id, accessToken, thunkAPI) =>
```

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator will tell you that there's only two arguments, and the second one is the thunk API. Try combining `id` and `accessToken` into an object:

async({ id, accessToken }, thunkAPI) =>

Also adjust the place where the thunk is dispatched:

```
dispatch(likeBook({ id: book._id, accessToken: user.accessToken }))
```

Also keep in mind that if `accessToken` is coming from the state itself, you could use the `thunkAPI.getState` to retrieve it. No need to select it in the component.